# JQuery using selectors for variables

Tags: jquery, html, variables, tabs

I am trying to create tabs using JQuery for a website. I got this to work:

```
$("#tabs_1").click(function(){
    $("[id*=tabc]").css({"z-index":0,"opacity":0})
    $("#tabc_1").css({"z-index":1,"opacity":100});
});
$("#tabs_2").click(function(){
    $("[id*=tabc]").css({"z-index":0,"opacity":0})
    $("#tabc_2").css({"z-index":1,"opacity":100});
});
$("#tabs_3").click(function(){
    $("[id*=tabc]").css({"z-index":0,"opacity":0})
    $("#tabc_3").css({"z-index":1,"opacity":100});
```

However I was wondering if there was a way to neaten the code... Maybe something like this:

```
$("#tabs_[x]").click(function(){
    var tab_num = x
    $("[id*=tabc]").css({"z-index":0,"opacity":0})
    $("#tabc_(tab_num)").css({"z-index":1,"opacity":100});
});
```

Comment: If you show the markup, I bet we can simplify the code *and* get rid of the `id`s entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [jquery attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). Try this:

```
$("[id^=tabs]").click(function(){
    var tab_num = this.id.split("tabs_")[1];
    $("[id*=tabc]").css({"z-index":0,"opacity":0})
    $("#tabc_"+tab_num).css({"z-index":1,"opacity":100});
});
```

Comment: Just FWIW, `$(this).attr("id")` is a really round-about way of writing `this.id`.

Comment: ^^ Was just going to say that, and I'll also suggest `tab_num = this.id.substr(5);`